# Condition for replacement of elements in an array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to define a condition such that whenever an element of `sigma1` becomes equal to or less than `0.010545`, the element is replaced by `0.010545`. The current and desired outputs are attached.

```
import numpy as np
sigma0=0.02109
a=0.001
b=0.001
t=np.linspace(0,20,10)
sigma1=sigma0-b*t
print("sigma1 =",[sigma1])
```

The current output is

```
sigma1 = [array([0.02109   , 0.01886778, 0.01664556, 0.01442333, 0.01220111,
       0.00997889, 0.00775667, 0.00553444, 0.00331222, 0.00109   ])]
```

The desired output is

```
sigma1 = [array([0.02109   , 0.01886778, 0.01664556, 0.01442333, 0.01220111,
       0.010545, 0.010545, 0.010545, 0.010545, 0.010545   ])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with boolean indexing:

```
sigma1[sigma1<= 0.010545] = 0.010545
```

Output:

```
sigma1 = [array([0.02109   , 0.01886778, 0.01664556, 0.01442333, 0.01220111,
       0.010545  , 0.010545  , 0.010545  , 0.010545  , 0.010545  ])]
```